# What are the Docusign API resource/rate limits? Are they active only in production?

Tags: docusignapi, rate-limiting

I found this document explaining what the resource/rate limits are for the docusign API. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/resource-limits However I didn't get any errors related to resource limits during development and testing. Are these only active in production environment? Is there a way to test these limits during development to make sure the application will work correctly in production? Is this document valid/up to date?

**Update (I just also want to expand my question here too)**

So there is only ONE TYPE of limit? 1000 calls per hour and that's it? Or do I also need to wait 15 minutes between requests to the same URL?

If the second type of limitation exists (multiple calls to the same URL in an interval of 15 minutes) does it apply only to GET requests? So I can still create/update envelopes multiple times in 15 minutes?
Also if the second type of limit exists can I test it in the sandbox environment somehow?

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The limits are also active in the sandbox system.

Not all API methods are metered (yet).

To test, just do a lot of calls and you'll see that the limits are applied. Eg do 1,000 status calls in an hour. Or create 1,000 envelopes and you'll be throttled.

### Added

#### Re: only one type of limit?

Correct. Calls per hour is the only hard limit at this time. If 1,000 calls per hour is not enough for your application in general, or not enough for a specific user of your application, then there's a process for increasing the limit.

#### Re: 15 minute per status call per envelope.

This is the polling limit. An application is not well behaved if it polls DocuSign more than once every 15 minutes per envelope. In other words, you can poll for status on envelope A once per 15 minutes and also poll once every 15 minutes about envelope B.

The polling limit is monitored during your application's test as part of the Go Live process. It is also soft-monitored once the app is in production. In the future, the monitoring of polling for production apps will become more automated.

If you have a lot of envelopes that you're polling on then you might *also* run into the 1,000 calls per hour limit.

But there's no need to run into issues with polling: don't poll! Instead set up a webhook via DocuSign Connect or eventNotification and we'll call you.

#### Re: limits for creating/updating an envelope and other methods

Only the (default) 1,000 calls per hour affects non-polling methods.

Eg, asking for the status of an envelope's recipients, field values, general status, etc, over and over again is polling. Creating /updating envelopes can be done as often as you want (up to the default of 1,000 per hour).

If you want to create more than 1,000 envelopes per hour, we'll be happy to accommodate you. (And many of our larger customers do exactly that.)

The main issue that we're concerned with is unnecessary polling.

There can be other unnecessary calls which we'd also prefer to not have. For example, the [OAuth:getUser](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints) call is only needed once per user login. It shouldn't be repeated more often than that since the information doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks. So there is only ONE TYPE of limit? 1000 calls per hour and that's it? Or do I also need to wait 15 minutes between requests to the same URL?